# Adaptable torrent variation

Tags: json, bittorrent

Looking for a similar solution to torrent protocol / BitTorrent application, where user can not only download and upload the same file, but user can modify the file, can add new keys to a JSON, can share with other, and other can refresh the content in their representation.

Do you know any similar solution?

Comment: Are there any restrictions why it should be similar to the torrent protocol? the case you describe could be satisfied with any file sharing / cloud solution

Comment: It is important, it should be peer-to-peer solution.

Answer (score 0):

[Syncthing](https://syncthing.net) is an open source peer-to-peer file synchronization program which lets users share and modify files and folders, as well as store previous versions.